# How to define aop:pointcut annotation in MultiActionController

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

I am new to Spring AOP, I want some help to

1. i have MultiActionController ,this is annotaion based.
2. i defined pointcut for method and advisor in spring configuration file.
3. i am calling that method from my controller.

Now my question is: How to define pointcut annotation in controller?

Please give me some hints.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of AOP is that you don't define the pointcuts in the target classes, but in external aspect classes (or in case of XML-based Spring AOP, in XML).

So if you have both your controller and the aspects in the same ApplicationContext (and the pointcuts match the controller methods), the advices should be applied automatically.

However, there is a caveat:

Spring AOP will only work the standard (JDK-proxy based) way if you use interfaces to back your controller.

If you do use interfaces consider this note ([source](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-sessionattrib)):

> **Note**
>   When using controller interfaces (e.g. for AOP proxying), make sure to consistently put all your mapping annotations - such as `@RequestMapping` and `@SessionAttributes` - on the controller interface rather than on the implementation class.

And if you don't, you must set `proxy-target-class="true"` as described in the section [Proxying mechanisms](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying).

Comment: Hi ,Thanks for your answer.I able to resolve my issue.Problem is my controllers are in different context and my aop definitions are in different application context.After i put all in one context,it started working.